# How can I build a private web widget (JS) that only trial or paid subscribers can use it?

Tags: javascript, ajax, security, widget, same-origin-policy

I'm building a web widget that must be private (only trial/paid subscribers can use it).

Yeah, I know there's no secure way to accomplish 100% of security using a client side solution (JS). However, my intention is just to make it as difficult as possible.

So, here's the thing:

The user must register and provide his site's domain during registration. After that, he will get a 7 day trial and can configure his widget on my control panel.

After configuration he will be able to copy and paste the JS snippet that will load the widget's content later on his site. Ex:

```
<script>
(function(){
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

        var token = 'f04e42bae1b330bdc35351f6f709f66b';
        var data = {'product_id': 123};

        $.ajax({
            url: 'https://myserver.com/widget.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: JSON.stringify(data),
            contentType: "application/json",
            beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', token);
            }
        }).done(function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        })

    });
})();
</script>
```

PS: the production version of this snippet would be obsfucated.

Now I need to be able to control on my backend who is trying to load my widget's content. Currently, I'm doing the following:

- Search for a user who has a token equal to the provided token and has an active subscription (trial or paid);
- If user is found, set header "Allow-Control-Access-Origin" and proceed with the widget logic;
- If no user is found, no header is set so browser will not load the content due to the "Same Origin Policy".

Ex:

```
<?php

$token = $_SERVER['HTTP_AUTHORIZATION'];
$productId = $_POST['product_id'];

$user = getUserByToken($token);

if($user){
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: //" . $user->domain);
    $w = new Widget($user);
    $items = $w->getItems($productId);
    ...
}

?>
```

Here is what Chrome responds when no "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" header is set (in case the token is not valid or is indeed valid but your origin domain does not match the one that is expected):

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://myserver.com/widget.php. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8001' is therefore not allowed access.
```

I understand that even if a user tries to use my widget on his site without paying for it using someone else's snippet/token, the "Same Origin Policy" will prevent him from doing so (browser will block it as above) because the domains will not match, right?

Is this method somewhat secure? Or there is a better and more secure way to accomplish this requirement? Any suggestions for the overall solution?

Thanks!

Comment: So the backend takes the key and domain and checks the db if it is valid and than it spits out the JavaScript code. That is basically how any api with subscription work.

Comment: @epascarello actually, I'm not sure if every API uses this header to control access: header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: //" . $user->domain); right?

Comment: I never said anyone uses a header. They normally take a request and generate the JavaScript. Not hard to detect if the api key is active and matches a domain.

Comment: A header would not stop a person from using a proxy to get around the CORS